# The meaning of “le titre va s’envoler”, and how to use it?

Tags: sens, usage

> Avec toutes les commandes à venir, **le titre va s’envoler**.

I wonder if it is used in a similar vein to "go through the roof" in English when an amount is skyrocketing?

Comment: It can also be used in not-so-particularly-exceptional situations. It's closer to “soar” in many respects.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez How would you express this sentence in English, incidentally? And what does "titre" in this expression refer to, exactlY?

Comment: I would translate it as "stock prices will hit the roof", or "share prices will hit the roof".

Answer (score 2):

Le [*titre*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2071671) (de bourse/boursier plus particulièrement), c'est la *valeur mobilière*, comme l'*action* de la société par exemple, échangée à la [bourse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourse_des_valeurs). Parfois ce peut être un [document](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/titre) qui atteste une telle réalité. Mais il ne faut pas les confondre avec le [*symbole boursier*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=507801), l'abréviation utilisée pour désigner un titre émis par une société cotée en bourse, le *titre* étant une catégorie conceptuelle (angl. surtout au pluriel, *securities*). On parle aussi du *[cours](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=cours%20boursier&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) en bourse/boursier/à la bourse*, voire d'une action. Voici un exemple d'emploi du verbe s'envoler avec le mot *titre* en contexte financier :

> Dès que la nouvelle a été connue, le 20 octobre, le titre s'est envolé
>   pour finir la séance sur une hausse de 3,7%.
>
> [ [Nouvel économiste](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6gxUJknnT5AC&q=%22le%20titre%20s%27est%20envol%C3%A9%22&dq=%22le%20titre%20s%27est%20envol%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfhq2EgdXXAhVJ7IMKHdyODPsQ6AEIQjAE), *Siparex, À l'abri d'un coup de tabac* (?),
>   1993 ]

---

Le verbe [*s'envoler*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envoler), en plus de prendre son envol concrètement, peut très certainement vouloir dire, entre autres, *s'élever*, voire subitement, et [*disparaître*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s_envoler/30168?q=s%27envoler#30081) (un peu comme [*s'en aller en fumée*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/fum%C3%A9e/35546/locution), *s'envoler en fumée* serait être emporté par le vent). [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=s%27envoler&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) présente le verbe avec d'autres locutions en contrepartie des termes employés en question et en commentaire, comme *partir en flèche, en fusée*, et l'idée *d'effervescence, d’ébullition*, dans tous les cas la métaphore de ce qui s'élève, la hausse, l'augmentation. C'est fort certainement employé directement avec le mot *prix*, pour l'augmentation, souvent rapide, similairement à l'idée d'*emportement* avec les prix qui *s'emballent* et la *[flambée](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flamb%C3%A9e) des prix*, visant l'ensemble des prix d'une catégorie de choses etc.

---

Avec le *titre* ou la *valeur mobilière*, dont l'action, ce qui *s'envole* c'est assurément la valeur présumée, et donc le prix qui grimpe, par métonymie ou ellipse ou autrement ; ce titre-là ne disparaît pas, il pourrait certainement faire l'objet d'un plus grand nombre de transactions, d'échanges, mais on parlerait sans doute davantage du [*volume de transactions*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=volume%20des%20transactions&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) que d'une *envolée* du titre. L'exemple en question laisse entendre que le cours de l'action, ou d'un autre titre d'une société, dont on parlerait, serait tributaire des ventes anticipées (les *commandes*) de la société. Plus généralement, selon ce qui s'envole et le contexte, hormis le prix et ce qui peut s'y rattacher où ce sera presque qu'exclusivement la *hausse*, possiblement fulgurante, on avisera au sujet du sens...